# Jackson : Updating (not creating new object) JavaObject from Json?

Tags: java, jackson

OK I have a json say

```
userjson = { fname : "ABC", lname : "DEF" }
```

and  a User Pojo Object

```
User {
 String id, 
 String email,
 String fname,
 String lname
}
```

now using the Jackson, I know how to create User instance from userjson, but how do i update existing User instance from userjson, because my user instance has some properties already set by some other Module.

For now what i am doing is converting userjson to userHasMap and then set all the values manually

```
userInstance.setFName(userHasMap.get('fname'))
userInstance.setLName(userHasMap.get('lname'))
```

which works fine, but I could have done some thing for converting userInstance to userjson when needed which would have made use of jackson-lib meaningless.

Comment: As it is using json coming from JavaScript, anyway I removed it.

Comment: Why would somebody close it, without giving any reason?

Comment: What is the semantic difference? Wouldn't those "properties set by some other module" have to be updated as well?

Comment: yes but not in same thread or one go, yes are being updated if i want to use jackson  to set what i will need to do is create temporary variables form existing one and then create new one and then set all those temps back to new One, its not lot of work and more importantly is that preferred?

Comment: It depends on your data structure. If the "properties set by some other module" are derived from the properties of the object, you should encapsulate them in that object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok found the answer, 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-857
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-824

```
mapper.readerForUpdating(object).readValue(json);
```

Comment: The given links aren't accessible. Anyone who have the new or updated links, please update in answer.